# Conditionally creating new collections with output parameters

Tags: c#, collections

This program is purely for illustrative purposes.  I wanted to take an integer as input and if it was greater than zero, create an ArrayList with that integer in the ArrayList.  I tried this numerous (incorrect) ways and eventually settled on what you see below.  However, I don't really like the looks of it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter in a number of the size of the ArrayList that you want: ");
            int arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (arraySize > 0)
            {
                ArrayList newList = CreateList(arraySize,out newList);
                newList.Add(arraySize);
                Console.WriteLine("the size of the array is {0}",newList.Count);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not create an ArrayList");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("here you can't access the array");
            Console.ReadLine();




        }
        public static ArrayList CreateList(int x,out ArrayList outList)
        {
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList(x);
            outList= al;
            return outList;

        }
    }
```

My thought process was that if a user decided on a certain action then the program wouldn't create an ArrayList to save resources (silly example considering the example, I know) . However, I still have to initialize an ArrayList in the main method, and if I take out the line `newList.Add(arraySize)` the program runs with an output of 0 if the user enters a number greater than 0.  Is there any way to make it so that any input greater than 0 will result in an ArrayList that's ready to go with the element added?  So if we commented out the line `newList.Add(arraySize)` the program would still print out the size of the ArrayList as 1 (provided that number was greater than 0)

In this example the number of elements is a maximum of 1, and not the number that the user might enter.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`. Use `List<T>`.

Comment: I'll do that in the future, but this was purely for illustrative,learning purposes

Comment: What is the purpose of CreateList method. You can do it directly ?!

Comment: @HusseinX I know, this is to enhance my understanding of how the language works.  That's why I prefaced the question with `This program is purely for illustrative purposes.` I want to see if there's something that I'm missing so I can apply that to a future situation.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking. " Is there any way to make it so that any input greater than 0 will result in an ArrayList that's ready to go with the element added?" As far as I can see you program already achieves this. What is that you are trying to find out?

Comment: Why use a return statement AND an out-parameter that both assign the same variable?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of things going wrong here.

Firstly, you can't *add* the size of the list. It's initialised in the constructor, and then it grows and shrinks as you add and remove elements.

So the line:

```
newList.Add(arraySize);
```

Is misleading and almost certainly not what you want. You either want to add an element (in which case the variable name is misleading) or you want to set the array's size or capacity, in which case the code isn't doing what you want.

There is also a difference between a list's *size* and *capacity* that you should probably be aware of:

- **Size** is the number of elements in the array.
- **Capacity** is the size of the list's underlying array, which will be equal to or greater than the list's *size* at any point in time.

**This is why your call to *Count* is returning 0 when you've initialised the list to some other value. *Count* refers to the number of items in the list, not the length of the internal array. You want to call the *Capacity* property instead:**

```
Console.WriteLine("the size of the array is {0}", newList.Capacity);
```

Lists (*ArrayList* and *List*) use array's internally, which are of a fixed size. So the capacity refers to the length of that array. And when you add a new element to a list whose array is full, the list's *Add* method creates a new array that is double the length of the old array, copies all the elements to the larger array, appends the new value at the end, and discards the old array.

So in short, the function:

```
public static ArrayList CreateList(int x,out ArrayList outList) {
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList(x);
    outList= al;
    return outList;
}
```

Is mostly okay, though somewhat redundant in that it should either use an out parameter or return the list, not both. For your case, I would do something like:

```
public static void CreateList<T>(int capacity, out List<T> list) {
    list = new List<T>(capacity);
}
```

Even though it's a pretty pointless method as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

One Comment:
You don't have to put a return type to the function try this:

```
ArrayList newList =null;
CreateList(arraySize,out newList);


public static void CreateList(int x,out ArrayList outList)
{
   outList = new ArrayList(x);
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement is invalid for a `void` method.

Answer (score 1):

Int parameter in `ArrayList` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa317761%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is "initial capacity", which is a performance feature (list is not resized while items are added until it reaches max capacity), so it does not make a difference to list's actual size. If you want to return a list with one item then add that item within your `CreateList` function.

Comment: I saw that in Intellisense and paid exactly 0 attention to it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Since, it's hard to understand from you explanation what the question is, I'm going to make a shot in the dark. Is this what you are after:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace SO16071463
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter in a number of the size of the ArrayList that you want: ");
            int arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (arraySize > 0)
            {
                ArrayList newList = new ArrayList { arraySize };
                Console.WriteLine("the size of the array is {0}", newList.Count);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You did not create an ArrayList");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("here you can't access the array");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```